# Getting an error "Suitetalk endpoint version 2014_2 is no longer supported" while using SuiteTalk SOAP service to connect to Netsuite database

Tags: oracle, netsuite, suitetalk

Getting an error **Suitetalk endpoint version 2014_2 is no longer supported** while using SuiteTalk SOAP service to connect to Netsuite database.
Any help is appreciated !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SuiteTalk endpoints are only supported back 3 years. Since the current WSDL version is 2021_2, only versions back to 2019_1 are supported.  Beyond that, NetSuite makes the next oldest eight endpoint available, but without support.  Currently, that goes back to 2015_1.  You will need to upgrade to a newer WSDL.  Be careful as there are consequences around authentication (user credentials vs token, and SHA-1 being deprecated for SHA-256) to watch out for, especially once you get past 2019_2.  For details, see this SuiteAnswer: https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10817